# Load UIView from UIViewContoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My Improve Code.....
I write the following code in ViewController.m viewDidLoad(). It already called my loadAnimate function.

```
self.classAnimate = [[animateClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 340, 320, 80)];
[self.classAnimate loadAnimate];
[self.view addSubview:classAnimate];
```

But when return cant load to my addSubview. I dont know what did I do wrong in loadAnimate() function at animateClass

```
-(void)loadAnimate
{
    NSLog(@"Calling from ViewController file");

    animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"adv01.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"adv02.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"adv03.png"],nil];

    campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:animationImages];
    NSLog(@"Images inside animationImages are: %@",animationImages);
    campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
    campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [campFireView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: just import the class and define a property......

Comment: There is no loadAnimate class in your code. You have a `loadAnimate` method on animateClass (which, incidentally, I'm hoping isn't your actual naming of the class…)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your `loadAnimate` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure I understand your code.

But, `campFireView` has been not added to the view hierarchy.

You do not call `loadAnimate`. `viewDidAppear` would be the right place to call it.

*Few notes*

Use **camelCase** notation. Classes should start with an upper case letter. So, `animateClass` should be `AnimateClass`. In addition, rename it as `AnimateView`. It's a view.